# Determine the smallest $\sigma$-algebra in $\Omega$ such that $(X,Y):\Omega\rightarrow\Bbb R^2$ is measurable.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Omega=\Bbb N$ and let $M_k$ be the set of multiples of $k\in\Bbb N$. Define  $$X:\Omega\rightarrow\Bbb R,\quad X(k) =\begin{cases}1 & k\in M_2\setminus M_4\\0 & k\in M_4\\
-1 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases},$$ $$Y:\Omega\rightarrow\Bbb R,\quad Y(k) =\begin{cases}1 & k\in M_{8}\\-1 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$ Determine the smallest $\sigma$-algebra in $\Omega$ such that $(X,Y)$ is measurable.

---

Now, for one random variable, I find this easy. Say if we were to find $\sigma(X)$ then this is \begin{align*}
\sigma(X)&=\sigma(\{X^{-1}(1), X^{-1}(0), X^{-1}(1)\})\\
&=\sigma(\{M_2\setminus M_4, M_4, \Bbb N\setminus M_2\})
\end{align*}
giving us the eight elements.

However, for two random variables for some reason I am finding things a bit tricky. Applying the same logic as above, we have $$\sigma(X,Y)=\sigma(\{(X,Y)^{-1}(1,1), (X,Y)^{-1}(1,-1), (X,Y)^{-1}(0,1), (X,Y)^{-1}(0,-1), (X,Y)^{-1}(-1,1), (X,Y)^{-1}(-1,-1)\})$$

so the first entry in the set ends up being something like $$M_2\setminus M_4\cup M_8$$ but do you take a union here or an intersection or what? That part had me a bit confused.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\sigma(X,Y) = \sigma(\sigma(X)\cup\sigma(Y))$. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that does help. Thank you very much!